# Prestashop start page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm developing a prestashop site but I don't want to have the shop as the starting page. I would like to have my corporate page as start page and link the shop as a menu option.

I'm really lost on how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1: You can install PrestaShop on a separate folder and link it from the menu.

Variant 2: If you need the header and the footer of PrestaShop and just the main content to be with your corporate information you can disable the Left Columnd and the Right Column modules to appear on the home ("index") page from Back Office / Modules / Positions / Edit (icon on the right side of the specific module for specific hook - displayLeftColumn, displayRightColumn)

Variant 3: If you need your corporate information on the center column, just uninstall all the modules from that column and leave only "Home text editor" where you can put your corporate information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have PrestaShop in separate folder like /store/ or /shop/ - then you can use WordPress, Drupal or whatever else you need to create corporate page.